# Hide My Account in Napili Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, napili, lightning-community

I built a Community with the Napili Template. Now I want to hide "My Profile" and "My Account" (under "Home") from the "Profile Header" component's picklist. How can I do that? I searched a solution and someone suggests to modify the community's css, but where can I find and modify the CSS?

Comment: I think this earlier q&a covers this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158173/add-standard-my-profile-component-to-a-custom-header-lightning-component - just want to test it works with current version of napili

Comment: I'm not an expert of custom lightning component and that picklist contains the logout functionality and I'm not feeling confident to override it. If I found a custom component out of the box maybe would work with some adjustment. What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you select the appropriate scope in your CSS, you can hide options in the Profile Header component:

For the profile menu option:

```
.profile.uiMenuItem{
    display: none;
}
```

You can modify the CSS under the branding options
[image]

However, this will affect all your users.

If you would prefer this to change based on profile (your admins might want to be able to access profiles easily) You might want to use Custom Theme Layouts, the feature is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

Comment: This works for "My Profile" but what about "my account"? I can't seem to make that one disappear.

Answer (score 4):

For the My Account menu option:

```
.myAccount.uiMenuItem{
    display: none;
}
```